# Combining to operations using java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm doing the below two operations

1. Iterating through a list of Objects and creating a map of `String, Boolean` based on a condition.

```
        Map<String,Boolean> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        Iterator<Person> iterator = personList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Person person = iterator.next();
                if (isValidperson(person)) {
                    if (person.getName() != null) {
                        myMap.put(person.getName(), true);
                    } else {
                        myMap.put(person.getName(), false);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now Im checking a list of Names against that map that I created above and if the value is true then adding to a final list

```
            List<String> refinedList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String name : nameList) {
                if (myMap.get(name) != null && myMap.get(name)) {
                    refinedList.add(name);
                }
            }
```

I need to simplify the logic using Java streams. The above works fine otherwise.

Comment: Why do you need the map at all? Can't you just add the people who are valid people and have non-null names directly to `refinedList`?

Comment: @Sweeper In second part of the code I actually loop through another list of Names and check their presence in the map. `            for (String name : nameList) {
`

Answer (score 3):

In the first operation you are filtering out all the non-valid persons, and collecting the valid persons to a map, so:

```
Map<String,Boolean> myMap = personList.stream()
    .filter(YourClass::isValidPerson)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getName(), x -> x.getName() != null))
```

But really though, the map is going to have at most one `false` entry, since you can't add multiple `null`s into a `HashMap`, so there isn't much point in using a `HashMap` at all.

I suggest using a `HashSet`:

```
Set<String> mySet = personList.stream()
    .filter(YourClass::isValidPerson)
    .map(Person::getName)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

And then you can easily check `contains` with O(1) time:

```
List<String> refinedList = nameList.stream().filter(mySet::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Or just `nameList.retainAll(mySet)`, when the original list is not needed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly filter the list by checking contains in `nameList` and collect the names in list

```
List<String> refinedList = 
    personList.stream()
              .filter(e -> isValidperson(e))
              .map(e -> e.getName())
              .filter(Objects::nonNull)
              .distinct()
              .filter(e -> nameList.contains(e))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And it better to create a set from `nameList` to make the `contains()` operation faster in O(1)

```
Set<String> nameSet = new HashSet<String>(nameList);
```

**Note:** This will works if `nameList` doesn't contains duplicate.

Comment: You have kind of changed the code's logic, haven't you? The code is supposed to get all elements of `nameList` that is a valid person's name, _not_ get all the valid persons' names that are elements of `nameList`. This code would produce different results if `nameList` contains duplicates, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

First, create a list of People.

```
List<Person> personList = List.of(new Person("Joe"),
        new Person(null), new Person("Barb"), new Person("Anne"), new Person("Gary"));
```

Then the nameList.  Note it is best to put this in a set to

1. avoid duplicates, and
2. make the lookup process more efficient.

```
Set<String> nameSet = Set.of("Joe", "Anne", "Ralph");
```

Now this works by

- filtering on a valid vs invalid person.
- mapping those people to a name
- filtering on whether null and then if the name is in the set of names
- and placing in a list.

**Note**:  In some cases, `lambdas` could be replaced by `Method References` depending on method types and calling contexts.

```
List<String> names = personList.stream()
        .filter(person -> isValidperson(person))
        .map(Person::getName)
        .filter(name -> name != null && nameSet.contains(name))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                
System.out.println(names);
```

Prints

```
[Joe, Anne]
```

Dummy method since criteria not provided

```
public static boolean isValidperson(Person person) {
    return true;
}
```

Simple person class

```
class Person {
    String name;
    
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```